# Biztalk: BTAHL72XSendPipeline adds line feed?

Tags: .net, biztalk, hl7

I'm using the BTAHL72XSendPipeline from Microsoft HL7 accelerator library in my Biztalk send port to assembly and send out HL7 message.

It is working well but the actual HL7 message contains both the Line Feed & Carriage Return after each line.  In another word I see \r\n after each segment termination, I don't have code to add these so I assume it is done by the BTAHL72XSendPipeline itself.

[image]

Our customer does not want the linefeed, is there a way to control this so that each line only has the carriage return instead of both?  I don't see how I can do this on the pipeline configuration.

Researching around the web gives me more confusion than answer for example:

According to the [HL7 Health Standard](https://healthstandards.com/blog/2007/09/24/hl7-separator-characters/), the segment terminator should only contain a Carriage Return (ASCII 13 or HEX OD).  According to that standard, this rule is not negotiable.

I also came across a PDF book "HL7 for Biztalk" written by Howard Edidin which states

[image]

So what now if my server is window based and the server which I send this to is Unix based, how can we resolve this line feed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, BizTalk send pipeline uses 'CR' (\r) as segment separator char. BizTalk send pipeline behavior can be changed for segment delimiter using following context property.

```
SegmentDelimiter2Char   True    Not Promoted    http://HL7Schemas.HeaderPropertySchema
```

There are two scenarios

1. You are receiving a HL7 from some source and then sending it out to somewhere else. If you disassembled this message, then context property is populated based on segment delimiter in original HL7 and message is generated by send pipeline accordingly.
2. If you are creating HL7 using schemas and then sending to pipeline, make sure this context property is not added and if it is added, its value should be set to false.

Comment: Hi Vikas, thank you for your input.  We have the in-house XML data that we run through a Biztalk map to produce DFT_P03 based data format (xml).  All these were done in the orchestration and finally send it to the HL7 Accelerator batching.  We use BTHAL72xSendPipeLine to capture the batch message and send it via MLLP to the destination as HL7 format.  So I think we fall to #2, does that mean I need to look at my orchestration prior to sending it to the Direct port?

Comment: Yes, that correct. Orchestration is probably writing the context property to true.

Comment: :(    hmm,, i checked it just now and I see our orchestration under the "Construct HL7 Message" has: msgHL7Out(BTAHL7Schemas.SegmentDelimiter2Char) = false;

Comment: You can stop the send port and see what context properties are there on message

Comment: I don't see SegmentDelimiter2Char in the list of the context properties, nor do I see others that we also set such as ZPartPresent, MessageEncoding, MessageClass.  Should they all be promoted for this to work?

Comment: yes, if orchestration is writing these properties, they should be there. By default pipeline should only emit '\r'. looks like there is something else going on there. Make sure you are checking the right flow and there are not multiple construct shape.